# Struts2- Persistence of objects values between different actions in the same Action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jaxb

**Scenario:** On click of a `Submit` button I have unmarshalled the XML to Java and then displaying the Java objects(created a formbean and mapped the JAXB java Objects to this formbean - `PolicyForm` and using this formbean to display in JSP) in the JSP. This is working fine.

**Issue:** I have one more button -`Calculate` on the same page with in the same form of `Submit` button. On click of the 'Calculate' button I need to get the `acordform` values which was unmarshalled during the click of `Submit` button. Here I am not able to get the `acordform` values instead I am getting the new object of `acordform`.

When I have googled I see - Struts 2 doesn't have thread-safety issues as "Action objects are instantiated for each request".

Please let me know here when I am sending the request again is the Action object- `acordform` being instantiated everytime? If yes, how can I avoid this? Since I need the `acordform`object values even in the next request too.

**Action Class:**

```
public class RateAction extends ActionSupport implements
        ServletRequestAware,SessionAware {

    /* ... */

    // ACORD xml form bean
    private ACORD acordform = new ACORD();

    //To display the values in the JSP
    private PolicyForm policyForm;

    public ACORD getAcordform() {
        return acordform;
    }

    public void setAcordform(ACORD acordform) {
        this.acordform = acordform;
    }

    public String doSubmit() {
       /*...Unmatshalling from XML to Java -acordform is done..*/
    }

    public String doRateSubmimt() 
    {
       /*..trying to get the acordform values which are being set 
         previously in doSubmit() method...*/
    }
}
```

**Strust.xml:**

```xml
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/" >

    <action name="fileUploadAction"
        class="com.main.common.action.RateAction" >
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">text/xml</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
             <interceptor-ref name="params"/>   
             <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>   
             <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/> 
         <result name="success">First.jsp</result>
         <result name="input">First.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="submitAction" class="com.main.common.action.RateAction" method="doSubmit">
    <result name="success">First.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="rateAction" class="com.main.common.action.RateAction" method="doRateSubmit">
        <result name="success">First.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**JSP:**

```xml
<s:form id="rtr" action="fileUploadAction" method="POST"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <s:file name="uploadFile" label="Upload Request XML" />
            <s:submit value="Submit" action="submitAction" onclick="displayDetails();" /> 
            <s:hidden name="submitSuccess" />
            <s:submit value="Calculate" action="rateAction" /> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you perform the operation in one click ? I mean Submit the XML, and draw the result with the unmarshalled XML...

If no, since you need to share that in-memory XML (not saved on HD nor DB, just posted to the Action) between multiple requests / actions, put it in the `Session Map` by implementing `SessionAware` in your Action.

Note that you are using too much Interceptors...

This should be enough:

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">text/xml</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Comment: I did try to place the acordForm in the session.However I still got the new object but not with the acordForm object values.Placed in setSession() methodsession.put("acordFormBean", acordform); And tried to get the acordForm object in doRateSubmit() method-ACORD acordformFromSession = (ACORD)session.get("acordFormBean");

Comment: Then your try failed :> Try harder. If you **succesfully** put an object in session, you will **succesfully** retrieve it later, with all its data inside.

Comment: Wanted to know if I can see the session objects of the Web appl anywhere other than while debugging??

Comment: You can print them in logs from the Action, and print them in JSP with `<s:property value="#session['yourObjectName']" />`

Comment: @crazy287 You can also use the `<s:debug/>` tag to see a whole bunch of useful information.